# Troubleshoot apk file

Tags: android, react-native

How can I troubleshoot an apk file which I created with react-native and Android Studio? It works to run in the expo dev environment. Then I ejected it into Android Studio and build an apk and build succeeded. But when I actually try and load the apk in my Samsung S8 phone it says that a problem occurred analysing the package. How can I proceed?

Comment: Do your phone already have a version of your app installed by mistake?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Nope. I'm trying to build it again using gradlew assembleRelease instead of building it from within AS

Comment: @ShobhitPuri The solution was to install it from "my files" instead of from the cache directly from the download link

Answer (score 1):

Just to double check, is the unknown sources / developer mode enabled on the S8?
https://www.technipages.com/galaxy-note8-s8-install-apk-file

Comment: Yes. The solution was to first download the apk file and then install it from "my files" in Android. Now it works. I could publish it to google play. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install it from "my files" instead of from the cache directly from the download link